# Offset CSS grid items on explicitly placed rows

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to achieve the following with CSS Grid Layout:

```
A                    A
B  B  B  B  B  B  B  B
C  C     E  E  E  E  E
         D  D  D
         F  F  F
```

I can add classes in the HTML but I cannot re-order the elements or add wrapping elements.

I have almost achieved this by using explicit `grid-row` values. Is it possible to position the last two rows starting at the fourth column **without explicitly specifying the `grid-column` property individually for each element**? (For brevity I've kept it to 6 here but there's more in the actual layout)

Here's what I have so far. As you can see, the two rows for `E` and `F` start on column 1.

I can add `grid-column: 4` to `.c13` but the subsequent elements in the row flow back to column 1.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 2em);
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.c2 {
  grid-column: 8;
}

.c16 {
  grid-column: 4;
}

.extra1 {
  grid-row: 4;
}

.extra2 {
  grid-row: 5;
}

.global1 { background-color: #ccc; }
.intra1 { background-color: lightblue; }
.intra2 { background-color: yellow; }
.intra3 { background-color: purple; color: white; }
.extra1 { background-color: orange; }
.extra2 { background-color: #f66; }
```

```html
<p>You need a browser that supports CSS Grid Layout for this.</p>

<section class='grid'>
  <div class='c1 global1'>A</div>
  <div class='c2 global1'>A</div>
  <div class='c3 intra1'>B</div>
  <div class='c4 intra1'>B</div>
  <div class='c5 intra1'>B</div>
  <div class='c6 intra1'>B</div>
  <div class='c7 intra1'>B</div>
  <div class='c8 intra1'>B</div>
  <div class='c9 intra1'>B</div>
  <div class='c10 intra1'>B</div>
  <div class='c11 intra2'>C</div>
  <div class='c12 intra2'>C</div>
  <div class='c13 extra1'>D</div>
  <div class='c14 extra1'>D</div>
  <div class='c15 extra1'>D</div>
  <div class='c16 intra3'>E</div>
  <div class='c17 intra3'>E</div>
  <div class='c18 intra3'>E</div>
  <div class='c19 intra3'>E</div>
  <div class='c20 intra3'>E</div>
  <div class='c21 extra2'>F</div>
  <div class='c22 extra2'>F</div>
  <div class='c23 extra2'>F</div>
</section>
```

Comment: For the most part, you're relying on the [grid item placement algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-placement-algo) to automatically lay out your grid items. This works until the visual order you want is the reverse of the source order. At that point, automatic placement fails because you're disrupting the logical order. That's why the `grid-column` property may be needed as an intervention, or you can try matching the source order with the visual order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add pseudo-elements to the `.grid` to block out the bits you don't want to use. CSS Grid will treat the pseudo-element as a grid-item and use up the space specified.
In your case these rules should work:

```
.grid:before{
  content:'';
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 4 / -1;
}
.grid:after{
  content:'';
  grid-column: 7 / 10;
  grid-row: 4 / -1;
}
```

Here's an example of it for you to play with: https://codepen.io/chrisboon27/pen/Lddpqa 
I added in the text and background-color to make it easier to see what is going on, but you would just remove those.